# RESTIFY: Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' on multiple requests

Tags: node.js, sockets, restify, econnreset

I am implementing a node app, which brings in order details from BigCommerce.
Multiple calls are made to BigCommerce API asynchronously using Restify JsonClient.

It works fine for some calls but after that i gives error:  `[Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET', sslError: undefined, body: {}`

I have tried turning off socket pooling ie by setting `agent=false`, but it still gives same error.

Following is code which makes call to BigCommerce API

```
makeRequest = function (url, params, headers, orderDetails, cb) {
                var options = {
              headers: headers
              };

                var client = restify.createJsonClient({
                    url: url
                });

                client.get(options, function(err, req, res, obj) {
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                        cb(err,obj);
                    } else if(obj != null) {
                        var result = obj;
                        if(orderDetails == null) {
                            cb(null,result);
                        } else {
                            cb(null, result , orderDetails);
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
```

I get following error:

```
{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET', sslError: unde
fined, body: {} } Error: socket hang up
    at SecurePair.error (tls.js:993:23)
    at EncryptedStream.CryptoStream._done (tls.js:689:22)
    at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:490:24)
    at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
    at EncryptedStream.onCryptoStreamFinish (tls.js:301:47)
    at EncryptedStream.g (events.js:175:14)
    at EncryptedStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:352:12)
    at endWritable (_stream_writable.js:359:3)
    at EncryptedStream.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:337:5)
    at EncryptedStream.CryptoStream.end (tls.js:628:31)
    at Socket.onend (_stream_readable.js:483:10)
```

Why am i getting such error? How can i handle it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's not the BigCommerce API that's closing the connection?

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to make sure that you're setting the agent setting in the right area.

Include the

> "agent": false

in your options.  (It's not set in the options in the code you pasted)

Per gfpacheco in the comments here: https://github.com/restify/node-restify/issues/485

> By default NodeJS uses agents to keep the TCP connection open, so you can reuse it.
>   The problem is that if the server is closed, or it closes your connection for whatever reason you get the ECONNRESET error.
>
> To close the connection every time you just need to set agent: false in your client creation

I've tried this solution and it worked for me.

Other than that, the

> "secureOptions": "constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2"

solution posted here sounds like it could be the right path, since you're getting an ***sslError***.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are running into this issue https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5360

TL;DR: You could try with latest node version and `secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2` added to your options.